# Element with opacity: 0 in CSS is not initially zero on page load

Tags: html, css

I want to set an element's opacity to 0 in CSS. But turns out, it's not actually 0 initially. If I set transition for opacity, it shows that the element is fully opaque first and slowly fades away. This is my CSS:

```css
.nav-overlay {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 9;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="nav-overlay">
     <h1>Test</h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it normal ? If I put the CSS class inside the `<style>` tag in my HTML, the element's opacity is 0 immediately. Why different behavior between putting the class in separate CSS file vs directly in HTML inside `<style>` tag ?

Comment: It might simply be the time needed for your file to be loaded and parsed.

Comment: I tried to make you a code snippet. Nothing is showing in the output.

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul hi, thanks for your reply. It seems that stackoverflow put my CSS directly inside my HTML when running the code snippet, so the element is immediately transparent as expected. I guess what Amaury Hanser said makes sense. But is there a way to make CSS files load and parsed first before inserting HTML elements to the DOM ?

Comment: Apparently the Browser first sees its initial CSS values before any transitions take place So the Browser sees `opacity:0;` and there is no transition yet. Use JavaScript to trigger the transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Amaury Hanser suggested, once the CSS file has been loaded and parsed, `opacity` is already at it's *default value* of 1.

You can set the initial value for `opacity` immediately in the HTML:

```
<div class="nav-overlay" style="opacity:0">
  <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```

Or you could write a script that adds your transition property **after** page load:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-overlay")[0];
  element.style.transition = "opacity 0.3s ease-in-out";
};
```

Either of these is fine, though I think setting the style on the html element *directly* is a little cleaner than using `<style>` tags within your HTML. (As long as it works for your case)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I actually don't want the fade away animation on page load. I want to element to be fully transparent initially. But I need the transition property set because if in the future I want to set the opacity to 1, I want it to change slowly instead of immediately be opaque

Comment: Ah I understand you now, I've edited my answer accordingly, hope it helps.

Comment: Then remove `.nav-overlay{ opacity: 0; }` and just add another class later like `.nav-overlay.vanish{ opacity:0; }` and do like `document.querySelector('.nav-overlay').classList.add('vanish')` when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of opacity as one of the guys said, what I do is using this javascript code to add a no-display class. This works for any element you don't want to be visible right after the page loads:

```
    export default function preventLoadingElement() {
    //Prevents opacity elements from appearing while loading
    let preventLoadingElement = document.querySelectorAll(".no-display");
    if(preventLoadingElement[0]) {
        preventLoadingElement.forEach(element => {
            if (element !== null) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    element.classList.remove("no-display");   
                }, 100);
            }     
        });
    }
}
```